# Python WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:

Tags: python

I am new to programming, this is actually my first work assignment with coding.  my code below is throwing an error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I'm not able to find where the issue is.

```
import os

folders = ["pdcom1", "pdcom1reg", "pdcomopen"]


for folder in folders:
    path = r'"C:\Apps\CorVu\DATA\Reports\AlliD\Monthly Commission Reports\Output\pdcom1"'
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        print file
```

Comment: You use Single and Double quotes. That might be an issue!

Comment: well, that was it!  Thank you.  Had added that outside single quote working a different solution, and I suppose I forgot to remove them.

Comment: Debugging tip: Ensure that the data you feed to functions that are seemingly misbehaving is correct. A simple `print(path)` would have shown that the double quotes were a part of the string's value.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As it solved the problem, I put it as an answer.

Don't use single and double quotes, especially when you define a raw string with `r` in front of it.

The correct call is then

```
path = r"C:\Apps\CorVu\DATA\Reports\AlliD\Monthly Commission Reports\Output\pdcom1"
```

or

```
path = r'C:\Apps\CorVu\DATA\Reports\AlliD\Monthly Commission Reports\Output\pdcom1'
```

Comment: Only conversion from a raw to a normal string helped in my case

Comment: Did you have the exact same problem? At the time I answered the question, I worked with python 2.7. never tried whether python 3 would behave different...

Comment: I use Python 3, but the symptom was the same. I guess it's not clear if it is the same problem because the error messages are quite unspecific.

Comment: True. I guess the core of my answer („don’t mix the types of quotes“) is valid in general, but it might not be enough in all cases. Can you identify characters which disable my solution? In case yes That would be worth a separate answer!

Comment: This is not working for me. Any other suggestion what could be wrong?

Comment: @AnanyaPandey My solution is now almost 8 years old, so it does not cover things happening after that. However, when receiving the error mentioned in the question, try to figure out it's not misspelling or mixing up single and double quotes. Once you assured that and it still doesn't work, feel free to ask your question providing your code and the occurring error.

Comment: @jkalden Thanks, I was able to figure out the issue, it is with the file name that my program was creating one of the chracters is not allowed by windows. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

I had a related issue working within Spyder, but the problem seems to be the relationship between the escape character ( "\") and the "\" in the path name
Here's my illustration and solution (note single \ vs double \\ ):

```
path =   'C:\Users\myUserName\project\subfolder'
path   # 'C:\\Users\\myUserName\\project\subfolder'
os.listdir(path)              # gives windows error
path =   'C:\\Users\\myUserName\\project\\subfolder'
os.listdir(path)              # gives expected behavior
```

Comment: The problem was double quotations on the string. OP is already converted the string to a raw string `r"path"`, so escape characters wasn't the problem.

Comment: I have the error ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users...\\xxx.csv' '``` , my code is using ```os.rename(r'C:Users\...\\xxxx.csv', r'C:\Users\...\xxxx_' + str(current_date) + '.csv')``` How can I solve it?

Comment: I had a similar issue in Jupyter with only some newly added sub-directories.  driving me crazy, but adding "r" before the quoted path using os.chdir fixed it.  Does r somehow tell the program that it is a path and not an escape character?

Comment: I had a similar issue with Python3 running on Windows 10. The problem was, I had one line in my .py file which had 
   os.makedirs('.\model') that worked, but another line 
   os.makedirs('.\tokenizer') which gave the error as in the title of this issue. 
It turns out \t is a special literal (tab) and is interpreted differently and hence gave this error.  Solution is to use \\ everywhere as this solution suggests.  The following worked.
   os.makedirs('.\\model') and os.makedirs('.\\tokenizer')

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with Django and it was because I had forgotten to start the virtual environment on the backend.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of an old question but I wanted to mentioned here the pathlib library in Python3.

If you write:

```
from pathlib import Path
path: str = 'C:\\Users\\myUserName\\project\\subfolder'
osDir = Path(path)
```

or

```
path: str = "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\project\\subfolder"
osDir = Path(path)
```

osDir will be the same result.

Also if you write it as:

```
path: str = "subfolder"
osDir = Path(path)
absolutePath: str = str(Path.absolute(osDir))
```

you will get back the absolute directory as

```
'C:\\Users\\myUserName\\project\\subfolder'
```

You can check more for the pathlib library [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had  a similar issue while working with Jupyter.
I was trying to copy files from one directory to another using copy function of shutil.
The problem was that I had forgotten to import the package.(Silly) But instead of python giving import error, it gave this error.

Solved by adding:

```
from shutil import copy
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same error with Django Rest Framework, It was nothing to do with UI, still was getting this error.
I applied below solution, worked for me.

- Restarted Machine.
- Restarted Virtual Environment.

Answer (score 0):

execute below

> Python manage.py makemigrations

It will show missing package.

Install missing package and again run below command to make sure if nothing is missed.

> Python manage.py makemigrations

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error though I did not use the path as in your case. The solution to my problem was to install the django-extension package.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the file count by sending path through a .robot file to one file count function which was a pyton file, but was getting the same error message. Below is the code

```
import os, os.path
count = 0
def get_file_count(desired_path):
   for path in os.listdir(desired_path):
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(desired_path, path)):
         count += 1   
   print('File Count:', count)
   return count
```

And the robot file was like

```
${download_dir}=     Join Path   C:/Users/user/Downloads
Log     ${download_dir}
${path}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    r    "${download_dir}"
${count}=    file_count.Get File Count    ${path}
Log    ${count}
```

The ${path} was storing the value as 'r"C:/Users/user/Downloads" but it was failing with above error message.
The solution I got for this was

```
import os, os.path

def get_file_count(desired_path):
   count = 0
   print(desired_path)
   for path in os.listdir(desired_path):
       if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(desired_path, path)):
           count += 1            
   print('File Count:', count)
   return count
```

Updated Robot file:

```
 *** Variables ***
 ${path}    C:\Users\user\Downloads

 *** Test Cases ***  
 Test
    ${count}=    file_count.Get File Count    ${path}    
    Log    ${count}
```

Just updated the path in robot file and moved count=0 inside the loop and it was working good for me.