# How to resolve OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:

Tags: python

i'm new to programming and i have a problem dealing with folder paths. The code is not perfect but it should work and the following is the snippet.

```
import os, shutil

os.chdir('D:\Document\Programmazione\Python\file_test\cats')
for foldernames, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if(os.path.getsize(filename) > 10):
            print(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

The error that i get is this:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\Document\\Programmazione\\Python\x0cile_test\\cats'
```

i tried different methods to resolve it and i saw that if i add a \ after python and before file_test it works partially giving me this other error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'automate-win-requirements.txt'
```

Thanks in advance for the help

UPDATE

I try the method suggested but nothing work for me, i attach the photo of the path to show you where it should go.

[File path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veunl.png)

Comment: `'D:\Document\Programmazione\Python\file_test\cats'` - you should either specify a raw string `r'D:\Document\Programmazione\Python\file_test\cats'` or use double backslashes: `'D:\\Document\\Programmazione\\Python\\file_test\cats'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python WindowsError: \[Error 123\] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618656/python-windowserror-error-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-s)

Comment: try using double backslashes, enclosing with double quotes.

Comment: I tried as suggested, but in both methods I get the same error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Comment: Not being funny, are you certain the path is spelled correctly?