# Cant install pandas on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

Im using python 3.8 and trying to install pandas on pycharm. It keeps giving me an error, thanks in advance !

Note: i have pandas downloaded on my interpreter but cant seem to 'link it' with pychar

Here's the error code:

```
Collecting pandas
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/1f/afb5cad013e8888053f6524849cc3df4bb83dfcab59485f10bf50016d4f8/pandas-1.1.1.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: still running...
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command "C:\Users\Heba 
Maamoun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Heba                      
Maamoun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip" install 
--ignore-installed --no-user --prefix "C:\Users\Heba Maamoun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
build-env-887ebusc\overlay" --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary 
:none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel Cython>=0.29.16,<3 "numpy==1.15.4; 
python_version=='3.6' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='3.7' 
and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and 
platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system=='AIX'" 
"numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; 
python_version>='3.8' and platform_system=='AIX'":
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't 
match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't 
match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't 
match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't 
match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't 
match your environment
Collecting setuptools
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/a9/5dc32465951cf4812e9e93b4ad2d314893c2fa6d5f66ce5c057af6e76d85/setuptools-49.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/00/3df031b3ecd5444d572141321537080b40c1c25e1caa3d86cdd12e5e919c/wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.16
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/4b/9e53bcce3c959fd0db143626e573210bba07be810fe8d7296373948c4183/Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy==1.17.3
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/d6/be8f975f5322336f62371c9abeb936d592c98c047ad63035f1b38ae08efe/numpy-1.17.3.zip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
Running setup.py install for numpy: started
  Running setup.py install for numpy: still running...
  Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'done'
 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:'


----------------------------------------

 Command ""C:\Users\Heba Maamoun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Heba Maamoun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip" install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix "C:\Users\Heba Maamoun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-887ebusc\overlay" --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel Cython>=0.29.16,<3 "numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system!='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.6' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='3.7' and platform_system=='AIX'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='3.8' and platform_system=='AIX'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Comment: Can you try [this way?](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: This is the way i did it, pycharm's giving me the error i mentioned above

Comment: Can you please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060353/not-able-to-install-packages-in-pycharm

The user seems to have similar problem

Comment: Did you try using command prompt to pip install pandas manually?

Comment: I did install it manually but it still doesn't register in pycharm for some reason. Any idea how i can fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, there is a space between your username Heba Maamoun. try to `remove the space` between your username in Windows/users and then try to install pandas again. You can set up a new account as an administrator and modify the name (including the folder name in C:\Users) in the current account.
let me know if this works for you ?

Comment: After some research it seems to be impossible to rename the folder name itself. So i made another account and made it the admin and its folder name is called "medoz", tried installing pandas again and now it just tells me that its installing and keeps going on forever.

Comment: Ok i just installed numpy and now it's all good and running thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

The error message says 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect',
maybe try retyping the command like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618656/python-windowserror-error-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-s#33624939).