# OSError [WinError 123] when using Jupyter within VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have used the Jupyter widget `# %%` within VS code all the time with no issue. Recently, I've gotten the error message

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

However, Jupyter notebook is running fine in Browser.

I have not defined any paths in my code and when I've created the virtual environment Jupyter was running fine within VS code.

Has someone experienced the same issue before and find where the problem lies? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to the problem

Usually [WinError 123](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is thrown when there is a usage of ":" Now this is not something you did, so I am assuming this comes from the extension you've used in [Jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).

Now all I can suggest is this *Re-installing the VSCode extension used for Jupyter* and then reloading VSCode.

### Disclaimer

If you've used "C:" in any of your open statements, you need to add make the string like this

```py
_str = r"c:\\helloworld\dummy.file"
```

Hope that resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the same as this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618656/python-windowserror-error-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-s).

The correct call is the following code:

```
path = r"C:"
```

If the problem cannot be solved, please paste part of your code.

Comment: Where do you edit the path?