# Failed to start kernel on Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, cell

I was setting up my Visual code studio so that I can start coding and integrating my database with python for sentiment analysis. I was successful in integrating the Jupyter extension with the visual studio code but I could not run the cell without getting the error.

```
    Failed to start the Kernel. 
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'.
```

[image]

Comment: Are you starting the kernel by doing `Ctrl + Shift + P` and `Jupyter: Select interpreter to start Jupyter server`? The selection poping up should be showing all the Jupiter kernels and their paths. You should normally be able to see if the kernels are what you were expecting

Comment: I did that too it did not work

Comment: Check perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078564/oserror-winerror-123-when-using-jupyter-within-vs-code)

Comment: Different issue as I can not run the cell for a simple library call

Comment: The solution in the post I linked, proposed to _reinstall the Jupyter extension_. Saying:  "I can not run the cell for a simple library call", you mean you can run the cell because you don't have a kernel, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I will try to reinstall the jupyter extension.